# Error when installing R package from Github

Tags: r, hash, devtools, rlang

I am trying to install package from github by the codes below.

```
devtools::install_github("news11/survELtest")
```

But the error messages say,

```
in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called ‘rlang’
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called ‘digest’
```

`rlang` and `digest` are dependencies of package `devtools`. So, it is strange that the dependencies are not installed after installing `devtools`.

Comment: *Why is it?* I don't understand your question. Are you asking *how* to install the dependencies? In fact, I cannot reproduce your issue. `survELtest` has no `rlang` and `digest` dependencies (neither the GitHub nor the CRAN version).

Comment: @MauritsEvers:  `devtools` depends on those two packages.  It looks as though it was not installed correctly.  Lann, run `install.packages("devtools")`, and its dependencies should be installed as well.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah that makes sense (somewhat). But since `devtools` seems to be installed (otherwise there would've been an error along the lines of "there is no package called `devtools`") it's odd that its dependencies were not installed.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Sorry, my question confused you. In fact, my question is why the dependencies are not installed after installing "devtools".

Comment: @user2554330 Greatly appreciate your response. It makes my question clear.

Comment: @Lann, how did you install `devtools`?

Comment: @user2554330 ```install.packages("devtools")```

Comment: That's strange, it should have installed all dependencies too.  Could you add the messages you see after running that again?

Comment: @user2554330 Did you succeed in installing `survELtest` and get one of data frames `hepatitis`?

Comment: @Lann Yup, `survELtest` intalls just fine (both the GitHub and CRAN version) and I can successfully access the `hepatitis` sample dataset.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for your time and effort. I think it is a rare error when installing `devtools`. After reinstalling `devtools`, everything becomes fine.